# Generate all substrings of a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, substring

I want to generate all the possible substrings from a given string without redundant values as follows:

input: `'abba'`

output: `'a','b','ab','ba','abb','bba'`

Here is my code

```py
s='abba' 
for i in range (0,len(s)):
    for j in range (i+1,len(s)):
        print(s[i:j])
```

My output is `'a','ab','abb','b','bb','b'`

As you can see from the output `'b'` is repeated, and `'bba'` does not exist.

I want to know and learn the right logic to produce all unique substrings.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want with a different string, e.g. `abcd`? `abba` is a bad example because the `ba` in the output could refer to either the last two letters of the input or  a combination of the first two letters.

Comment: here is another input

'ifailuhkqq'


output 
'i','ifa','fai'

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the indexing a bit

```py
s='abba' 
for i in range (0,len(s)):
    for j in range (i,len(s)):
        print(s[i:(j+1)])
```

yields the following output

```
a
ab
abb
abba
b
bb
bba
b
ba
a
```

Basically, the indexing fix takes into account that

- `'abba'[3:3]` produces just zero-length string `''`

but

- `'abba'[3:4]` produces string `'a'` which has length one.

Duplicates you may remove by using `set()`, as follows:

```py
s='abba'
ss = set()
for i in range (0,len(s)):
    for j in range (i,len(s)):
        ss.add(s[i:(j+1)])
        
print(sorted(ss))
```

Then you will have the following result `['a', 'ab', 'abb', 'abba', 'b', 'ba', 'bb', 'bba']`.

Comment: And to remove duplicates, add the values to a set.